# How to query contents between headings?

Tags: selector, typst

Is *selector* in Typst able to select contents between headings?
I have three headings, eg: **Test1**, **Test2** and **Test3**,
how to extract/query the contents between these headings?

The result is 10 words generated by `#lorem(10)`, and the content "Hello World. \n Hello Again.", and the content "This is test3 \nThis is test3 too".

The below query can only select headings itself, and I don't know how to select/extract the contents between headings?

```
= Heading

#locate(loc => {
  let elems = query(
    selector(heading.where(level: 2)).after(loc),
    loc
  )
  if elems.len() > 0 {
    elems.last()
  } else {
    [Test]
  }
})

== Test1
#lorem(10)

== Test2
Hello World. \
Hello Again.

== Test3
This is test3 \
This is test3 too
```

Comment: I don't think that this is possible currently. Only some elements are locatable. There is a [discussion](https://github.com/typst/typst/issues/1356) though about extending that.

Comment: thanks for your attention, I'll keep an eye on it.